# Pip freeze throws an error after uninstalling robotframework

Tags: python, pip, robotframework

I attempted to upgrade robotframework which failed using MacOS High Sierra v 10.13.6. I then tried to uninstall it to do a clean install. When I try to use pip I now get the below error. I'm using python 2.7.15 and pip version 19.0.1. 
Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be appreciated:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 176, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py", line 93, in run
    for line in freeze(**freeze_kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py", line 62, in freeze
    req = FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py", line 239, in from_dist
    req = dist.as_requirement()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2716, in as_requirement
    if isinstance(self.parsed_version, packaging.version.Version):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2551, in parsed_version
    self._parsed_version = parse_version(self.version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2589, in version
    raise ValueError(tmpl % self.PKG_INFO, self)
ValueError: ("Missing 'Version:' header and/or METADATA file", Unknown [unknown version] (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue relating to latest version of [pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6194):

Someone fixed their system by deleting remaining data from their python site-packages directory:

> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot

Also there will be something like this in site-packages directory which should be deleted also:

> ./robot-3.1.dist-info/METADATA

Perhaps downgrading pip might also help avoid the issue although I don't see any mention of that in the ticket.

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't try downgrading pip but I'll try your suggestions.